# Cant find bios update for Gigabyte motherboard

Tags: ssd, motherboard, bios, software-update

I am having a hard time finding a bios update anywhere online for the Gigabyte Motherboard GA-P67A-UD3R-B3.

Its on bios version F2 which is way outdated and im having trouble having it boot from an ssd so im hoping a bios update will fix my problem.

Can anyone please direct me to the right place?

I am going to keep looking in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

First result of a Google search got me into the motherboard's page.

The latest version available is the [F9 (2012/03/21)](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-P67A-UD3R-B3-rev-11/support#support-dl-bios) one. Have in mind the BIOS update is an advanced process and you should check the instructions/manual before proceeding.